# What is the meaning of the "d(...)2" notation when writing a DNA sequence?

Tags: biochemistry, dna

When the sequence of a DNA oligo is written as `d(CGCTAGCG)2` what is the meaning of the `d(...)2`?  Why would it not simply be written as `CGCTAGCG`?

I recognize this sequence is the complement of itself.  Is that what this notation indicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking to the author of [this publication](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.5b00508), they used `d(...)` to denote a double-stranded sequence and `d(...)2` to denote a self complimentary double-stranded sequence.

[This publication](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/10/3534) instead uses the subscript number after the parenthesis to denote the number of repeats in the sequence, e.g., `d(AT)10` was used to represent the dsDNA sequence `ATATATATATATATATATAT`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you were referring to [this specific usage](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?pdbId=1g7z) of `d(CGCTAGCG)2`, the image provided for the crystal structure clearly shows that the structure refers to the fact that two strands of **d**eoxy-ribonucleotide oligos were dimerised to each other.

Had the same structure been formed by double-stranded RNA instead, the resultant dsRNA duplex helix would be referred to as `r(CGCTAGCG)2`

[image]

Comment: If I understand, the `d` refers to DNA and the `2` refers to double-stranded, correct?  If I want to refer to [triple-stranded DNA](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore.do?structureId=1d3x) would I then use `d(...)3`, etc?  (The sequence I posted actually came from a study of the middle 8 bp of [PDB ID: 1DCV](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1DCV) but the structure should be quite similar to PDB ID: 1G7Z and it should not affect the answer.)

Comment: @stvn66 If they were 3 independent molecules hydrogen-bonded together, sure.

Comment: Can you point to any sort of reference which verifies your description of the notation?  This would allow me to more confidently mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @stvn66 I assume it is because of standard chemical nomenclature for dimerised molecules, and I don't think there will exist a source that says this for DNA specifically.

Comment: Reading [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja044533%2B), they reference 'd(A)10-d(T)10'.  This seems to indicate the DNA sequence 'AAAAAAAAAA' and its complement.  Therefore, I do not think the '2' refers to it being double stranded, but instead that the molecule have 2 copies of that DNA sequence, since it is the complement of itself.